# Django/HTMX - How to stop resetting selected option when search form is submitted?

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms, htmx

I want to implement a search form that has a **Product ID** field and a and **Product locations** select field in which the list of locations should be populated based on the Product ID entered.

For the Product ID, I'm using HTMX, to get the list of available locations dynamically. Which means, whenever I type any Product ID, I want to get all the available Locations for that ID without having to click on a button.

And when the Location is selected and the Search button is clicked the search result should be displayed in the page.

BUT the problem is, whenever I click select an option and click on the Search button, It reloads the page and resets the selected option! and this is not what I want, I want to keep the location as selected when the search result is displayed.

How can I stop resetting the select input after selecting when the Search button is clicked and the page is reloaded?

Template:

```
  <form method="get" action="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="me-2">{{filter_form.name}}</div>
        <div class="me-2">{{filter_form.category}}</div>
        <div>
          <button name="product_search_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Form:

```
class ProductSearchForm(forms.Form):
    id=forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"hx-get":reverse_lazy("shop:product_locations"), 
                                                      "hx-trigger":"load, change", "hx-target":"#locations_select", "class":"form-control"}))
    locations=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={"id":"locations_select", "class":"form-control"}))
```

Views:

```
class ProductLocationsList(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context={}
        if "name" in self.request.GET:
            locations=Product.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET["id"]).values_list('location', flat=True)
            context['locations']=locations
            return render(request,"shop/product_locations.html", context)
        return



class ProductList(TemplateView):
    template_name = "shop/product_list.html"
    filter_form=None

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.filter_form=ProductSearchForm(initial=request.GET or None)
        return super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["filter_form"] = self.filter_form
        return context
```

Urls:

```
 path('products/', ProductList.as_view(), name='product_list'),
 path('products/locations', ProductCategoryList.as_view(), name='product_locations'),
```

Comment: To prevent the page reloading you would have to send a [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) request to a view that returns [`JSON`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). And then update the template also using `JavaScript` with the response data. But you do not necessarily need to do that, you can handle the `POST` request in a different manner and pass extra information to the template, to set the selected field.